# Tweet analysis on Python

Tags: python, twitter

I have the following code in Python:

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta

def tweets_user_student(user):
  search_params = { 'screen_name': user,'result_type': 'recent', 'count': 1} 

  search_url = '{}1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json'.format(base_url)
  search_resp = requests.get(search_url, headers=search_headers, params=search_params)
  Data = json.loads( search_resp.content.decode("utf-8") )

  for tweet in Data:
    <GAP_1>
    if <GAP_2>:
        tweets_user_student = {tweet['user']['screen_name']: tweet['user']['followers_count']}
        dict_tweets_student.update(tweets_user_student)
        print(tweets_user_student)
    
list_users_student=[<GAP3>]
dict_tweets_student={}
for user in list_users_student:
  tweets_user_student(user)

print(dict_tweets_student)
```

I need to show for each of user, the number of followers analyzing the tweets of the last week.

I show the number of tweets of two users, made during the last week. To do this, I can use the datetime module and the date and timedelta objects, but I do not know how to do it. Does anyone could help me? How can I fill those GAPS?

Thank you!

Comment: This is literally not possible, because the Twitter API doesn’t provide any feature for “the number of followers analyzing the tweets of the last week”. If that is your class assignment, I’d mention this to your supervisor.

Comment: You are right Andy. The first sentence is wrong and it is not related with the class assignment. Do you think it is possible to find the solution to this code? I am not sure how to use the class datetime.timedelta in here. I also don't know what should be the value of list_users_student. Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying this but it doesn't work:

week_ago = date.today() - timedelta(7)
if  week_ago < datetime.strptime(tweet['created_at'], '%a %b %d%H:%M:%S+0000 %Y'):
Can someone help me, please? Thank you.